# If statement in python Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I've a dataframe called family in pandas that I've created following an sql code. I've done all of it except this line. The sql code is the following

```
SELECT IF(name Is Null, family.last_name, family.first_name) as family.NAME
from family
```

I've tried the following

```
family['NAME']= np.where(family[family.name.isnull()],family.last_name, family.first_name)
```

But I'm not getting anywhere, any help is appreciated. The dataframe looks something like this

```
name:    first_name:    last_name:
Peter    Peter          Smith
NaN      Phil           McGrath
Jack     Jack           Jones
NAN      Fred           Hogan
```

I want it to get me a new column that would look like this

```
NAME:
Peter
McGrath
Jack
Hogan
```

Comment: try this: `np.where(family.name.isnull(),family.last_name, family.first_name)`

Comment: thats it! thanks Max, feel free to add that as the answer and ill verify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy.where(condition[, x, y])](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function expects `bool` values as a `condition` argument:

> **condition :** array_like, bool
>
> When True, yield x, otherwise yield y.

so you can do it this way:

```
np.where(family.name.isnull(),family.last_name, family.first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

As MAXU said

```
family['NAME'] = np.where(family.name.isnull(),family.last_name, family.first_name)
```

was the correct code

Comment: You're supposed to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) MaxU's answer, not write your own copy :)